# Is it valid to optimize speed for text rendering, and then asynchronously optimize legibility via a deferred stylesheet?

Tags: css, performance, typography

<strike>`text-rendering: optimizeLegibility` is the [default for most modern browsers](https://caniuse.com/#search=text-rendering).</strike> (Edit: Not true, but leaving for posterity.)

However, there is a [considerable performance](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/text-rendering/) gain from `text-rendering: optimizeSpeed`.

Currently, I have my above-the-fold/critical styles inlined, with my below-fold styles deferred asynchronously using [rel=preload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Preloading_content).

My question is if it would be valid* or worth it** to initially, in my critical styles, use `text-rendering: optimizeSpeed`, and then in my deferred/asynchronous stylesheet, switch to `text-rendering: optimizeLegibility`?

* validity defined as working the way you'd expect. "Optimize speed" is used initially, and then when the deferred stylesheet loads asynchronously, "optimize legibility" is used instead.

** worth it defined as any more-than-negligible performance gains in proportion to the (simple) process of switching the styles in my SS.

Comment: "text-rendering: optimizeLegibility is the default for most modern browsers." That's not true. The initial value is auto, which both Chrome and Safari treat as optimizeSpeed. Firefox is the only one that intelligently switches auto between optimizeSpeed and optimizeLegibility depending on the font size. caniuse.com doesn't appear to have a citation for its statement "Newer browsers have this behavior enabled by default."

Comment: @BoltClock Ah okay, thanks for the clarification. I suppose my question still stands; if Chrome and Safari use optimizeSpeed, and my inlined-critical SS starts with optimizeSpeed as the default, should/could I then use optimizeLegibility asynchronously?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I think I've since answered my own question, so I'll leave a few things here for posterity:

- The answer to the core of my question: Blanket-applying `optimizeLegibility` is *slow*, from ***initial render time to repaints***. So my conclusion is that even loading it asynchronously isn't worth it, as it can delay the loading of the async stylesheet and cause FOIT [[1]](https://bocoup.com/blog/text-rendering) (especially when applied to long strings of text).
- As BoltClock pointed out, Chrome and Safari use `auto` by default, while only Firefox switches intelligently at a 20px threshold. Moreover, though, *Chrome and Safari treat `auto` as `optimizeSpeed`*. [[2]](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-rendering) So declaring oS in my above-fold styles is basically redundant anyway.

  - I think perhaps most importantly, this demonstrates `optimizeLegibility` is not at a point where it can be used without special exception, as Chrome and Safari aren't even comfortable using anything other than `speed` where other options like `precision` aren't specified.
- Not only is there a lack of support in some older browsers, there are in fact deal-breaking bugs in others, [[2]](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-rendering) meaning `text-rendering: optimizeLegibility` is not viable for progressive enhancement (at least PE via deferring below-fold styles).

Lastly, I [submitted an issue](https://github.com/Fyrd/caniuse/issues/4545) on caniuse's repo to correct the erroneous claim that modern browsers default to `optimizeLegibility` (thanks to BoltClock for pointing that out).

**TL;DR** Is it valid? Technically, but the first part is redundant. Is it worth it? Not only is it not worth it, there are performance and unanswered bug concerns.